# Yammer Embed Share Functionality not Fetching og meta tag content

Tags: yammer

We used Yammer embed share button on SharePoint Publishing Article Pages as specified here: [Yammer Social Actions](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/share-button).

However, the title, description and image content is not fetched from og meta tags. Please suggest if there is any mistake in following syntax:

```
<meta content="Sean Connery found fame." property="og:description">
<meta content="The Rock" property="og:title">
<meta content="article" property="og:type">
<meta content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" property="og:url">
<meta content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" property="og:image">
```

Comment: What do you see with the Embed.ly explorer when you enter your page URL into http://embed.ly/docs/explore/extract? Embed.ly is the system used for extracting the metadata used by Yammer. If you continue to have issues a Support Case with Microsoft may be the best bet. If your pages are authenticated then Embed.ly cannot reach them and you'd need to post the metadata in some other way to Yammer (Comment Feed, Activity Stream item, or with og_ properties of a Message post through the REST API.)

Comment: Thanksfor your reply, I tried entering the intranet URL in the embed.ly Explore Extract page and it gave me an error. So now I'm using REST API method to share the article.